# What should we put in [writing]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

<sup>*I'm being a little self-indulgent with a slightly punny title for a tag cleanup request, because SE tradition!*</sup>

[writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) is *supposed* to be for questions "specifically related to written English", as opposed to spoken. That's actually not all that common a subject, probably since most of the interesting stuff to learn is already taught by the time someone can type out a question, or is specific to writing by hand (and thus rather dubious to ask on a computer). But unfortunately the tag is also a honeypot for questions about *composition*, i.e., "writing things". This is of course dead wrong, and in fact those questions are almost always outright off-topic, because the proper way to structure an essay or business letter is entirely out of our site scope.

What should we do about this?

- Add to the <strike>wiki excerpt</strike> usage guidance, which users on SE seldom read and users on ELL almost never do?
- Rename the tag? This would be my preference; I'd suggest [written-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-english).
- Attempt to use the tag as a filter to catch bad questions? Probably a bad idea, since there are perfectly legitimate questions asked in it, and deliberately allowing honeypot tags is a dubious practice anyway.
- Throw up our hands and ignore the problem, as is the case for a distressingly large number of tags anyway?
- Something else?

Answer (score 4):

I would support the change to [written-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-english), because there is far less room for (mis)interpretation. If this change gets significant support from the community (read: some upvotes and no strong opposition and/or alternative), I'd be happy to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [written-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-english) would be used more appropriately than [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing).

[written-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-english) **might** get applied less, but only because it is a less obvious tag name than [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing).

Comment: Even if it didn't have a big impact in practice,  I would support the change because it makes the tag name more precise, without making it more obscure. If someone starts typing in writing, written-english should come up in the suggestions. Every little bit of guidance helps IMO.