# Should the "writing" tag be changed to "written-english"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

So [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing), which has the description *For questions specifically related to written English.*, has been applied to many questions and very few of them are specifically focused on written English.

It's not a good tag, but changing the name to "written-english" would make it more obvious what the intended use of the tag is and it would mirror [spoken-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-english). After looking at the questions tagged with [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing), I thought maybe it should be black listed, but I don't feel strongly about it.

We discussed this a few years ago in [What should we put in [writing]?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/what-should-we-put-in-writing) but there was no real consensus, so I'm bringing it up again.

#### I've added some more explicit options to vote on. If there is an option I didn't include that you think I should have, please add an answer.

Comment: As a recently active contributor to ELL I am surprised the tag hadn't already been updated. Of course the differentiation should not taken as 'nit-picking' specifics about English. It's just that spoken English is often much different then written English.

Comment: @GWarner I honestly wonder if we need a "written-english" tag at all. I think the spoken-english tag is helpful, but that there's not much reason to specify that a question is about written English unless we're talking about [tag:orthography]. Maybe it should be a synonym of that instead.

Comment: I misread the question. No matter. My thoughts are that a non-English native (speaker, writer, reader) have difficulty understanding there is an actual difference between written English and spoken English. The [writing] tag would often be misused because of this and specific tags would only be good for future reference. Added by editors after the fact.

Comment: Not a regular, but I'd support do something with [writing] tag because it's so ambiguous (an act of writing? [handwriting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/228990/11157)? [reading comprehension](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225532/11157)?), but before that, I think we should discuss the intended scope of the tag first (and later clean up the wrongly tagged questions...).

Answer (score 4):

Up-vote this answer if you think the writing tag should be left alone and we should just remove it from the questions that aren't focused on written English.

## Leave [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) alone

Answer (score 3):

Up-vote this answer if you think the writing tag should be replaced with written-english and a synonym added.

## Replace [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) with [written-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-english)

Comment: Obviously like a sun in the mid summer, "writing" ( Yes, it would be same with "writing" SE mostly, I think. ) and "written" "English" is so conspicuously different. As @Mari-Lou A proposed prior, the audio functions are not yet well embedded at this site, most of the questions are related with "written"(by another writer) English. Writing and written is universally different.

Answer (score -5):

Up-vote this answer if you think the writing tag should be removed entirely.

## Remove [writing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing)